# Fixed string Regular Expression C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

Hi all I want to know something regarding to fixed-string in regular expression.
How to represent a fixed-string, regardless of special characters or alphanumeric in C#?

For eg; have a look at the following string:

**infinity.world.uk/Members/namelist.aspx?ID=-1&fid=X**

The entire string before X will be fixed-string (ie; the whole sentence will appear the same) BUT only X will be the decimal variable.

What I want is that I want to append decimal number X to the fixed string. How to express that in terms of C# regular expression.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Are you trying to extract `X` and append it to somewhere else??

Comment: The same place (ie; after the last = character)
Thanks

Comment: There is absolutely no need for a regular expression here.

Comment: @Arean: So why bother with regular expression. just concatenate whatever you need to the string i.e. `yourstring+value` ??

Comment: @Arean: Also next time, try to give a proper question title!!

Comment: @Arean, do you understand what a Regular Expression is?  To put it simply, it's a way of finding patterns of characters within a string.  I think everyone who has read this question is having a difficult time understanding how a Regular Expression would be used while appending text to the end of a string literal.

Comment: @Arean I suggest you to **edit your question** to make clear what you need (parsing web page, you don't have such ready to use string where you can append a number). Moreover **if you can't assume something about that URLs it may not be a good idea to use regex** (because there are many URLs in a web page such as links, stylesheets, src, microdata and others). Yes you can do that parsing with _some_ regex engines but it's much much easier to search for links with an HTML parser.

Comment: @Jim you can replace the argument with a regex ( ``Regex.Replace`` ), but is not a good idea to use regex ( or ``string.Replace`` ) to manipulate url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to modify existing url, dont use regex, `string.Format` or `string.Replace` you get problem with encoding of arguments

Use Uri and HttpUtility instead:

```
var url = new Uri("http://infinity.world.uk/Members/namelist.aspx?ID=-1&fid=X");
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query);

query["fid"] = 10.ToString();

var newUrl = url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) + "?" + query;
```

result: `http://infinity.world.uk/Members/namelist.aspx?ID=-1&fid=10`

for example, using `query["fid"] = "%".ToString();` you correctly generate `http://infinity.world.uk/Members/namelist.aspx?ID=-1&fid=%25`

demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zZ9Y1h

Comment: Ah...Thanks, your solution is what I need. But the problem here is I don't know what value X contains. And I can know only after I have retrieved the matching links from the web I scan?

Comment: sure, you can parse any url and change ( or add or remove ) every query arg

Comment: Oh, I see. HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(x) parses and returns back  multiple occurrences of the same query string parameter. In this case, it will return all occurrences of the link specified in Uri(). Cool.

Comment: Exactly. usually is always a good idea to use already existing bcl classes to parse/manipulate/format, instead directly using string/regex methods

Answer (score 7):

```
string fulltext = "inifinity.world.uk/Members/namelist.aspx?ID=-1&fid=" + 10;
```

Comment: If this is what OP wants then you deserve 1000^0 upvotes because you did understand it and he deserves 10^1 downvotes because of his question...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti OP stated, *"What I want is that I want to append decimal number X to the fixed string"*

Comment: yes, I saw it but I thought "no, he **must** be something else"

Comment: LOL. I MEAN IN TERMS OF REGULAR EXPRESSION method

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti and 1000^0 is just 1 :(

Comment: @clcto yes, you didn't use regex as required! ;)

Comment: @clcto: All he wanted was to make it seem like a huge number. You've been fooled :p

Answer (score 0):

String.Format is one way of replacing token values in a string, if that's what you want.  In the example below, the {0} is a token, and String.Format takes the fixedString and replaces the token with the value of myDecimal.

```
string fixedString = "infinity.world.uk/Members/namelist.aspx?ID=-1&fid={0}";
decimal myDecimal = 1.5d;
string myResultString = string.Format(fixedString, myDecimal.ToString());
```